# Does the Schouten tensor vanish along geodesics?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, geodesic

> Let $(M,g)$ be a semi-Riemannian manifold.
>   Let $\gamma : I \rightarrow M$ be a geodesic.
>   Denote by $P= \frac{1}{n-2} \left( Ric- \frac{scal}{2(n-1)}g \right)$ the Schouten tensor.
>   Does $P(\gamma'(t),X)=0$ hold for all $t \in I$ and all $X \in T_{\gamma(t)} M$?

The question arose after reading "Differential Geometry, Valencia 2001", edited by Gil-Medrano, Miquel, page 257, Proposition 2. ([Link to Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=F9DUCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=schouten+tensor+along+geodesic&source=bl&ots=jA6rrQ47Iz&sig=9r9Zi0GjFSD4dQKzTQslhwJHNd8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFvIqs6dzOAhXJWRoKHT5KAxQQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=schouten%20tensor%20along%20geodesic&f=false))
It seems the author uses a different notion of Schouten tensor there.
Also "An extension theorem for conformal gauge singularities" by Tod, Lübbe, page 13, Proposition 2.1 ([Link to Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.5552.pdf)) seems to contradict the claim and rather suggest the following:

> There exists a conformally equivalent metric $\tilde{g}$, such that $\gamma$ is a geodesic with respect to $\tilde{g}$ and the Schouten tensor $\tilde{P}$ induced by $\tilde{g}$ vanishes along $\gamma$, i.e. $\tilde{P}(\gamma'(t),X)=0$ for all $t \in I$ and all $X \in T_{\gamma(t)} M$.

Sadly I am not familiar with the methods used in either source, so I cannot really follow the proofs.
I was hoping to receive the result with elementary methods.
That means:
So far I tried introducing a local, parallel orthonormal basis $(s_i)$ and directly compute $P(\gamma',s_i)$, but after expanding I can see no reason why the terms there should cancel out.